# Virtualbox: 2-Finger-Touchpad-Scrolling on Win10 Guest very choppy (Ubuntu 20.04 Host)

Tags: virtualbox, mouse, synaptics

After finally taking the plunge and upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04 I think I've hit the first snag:

- **2-Finger-Touchpad-Scrolling** (Thinkpad X1) on **Win10 Guest** has become very choppy / unusable (Ubuntu 20.04 Host).
- In contrast to the touchpad, scrolling with a USB mouse wheel works well/normally/smoothly.
- Guest Additions on the Win10 Guest are installed.

Google so far yielded two relevant hits:

1. https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=93857&start=15 and
2. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2444679.

The solution propounded by the former (running `QT_XCB_NO_XI2=1 VirtualBox` in terminal) unfortunately did not do the trick yet for me... The latter does not yet offer a (bug?) fix / solution, but only confirmation of the problem, as it were.

How to fix?

---

*This is the proposed solution [from number 1. above](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=93857&start=15) (which doesn't seem to work for me):*

> The problem is that XInput2 smooth scroll events are not being
> received by the guest.
>
> To see this, listen for XInput2 events on the host and the guest by
>
> ```
> xinput --test-xi2
> ```
>
> When scrolling, only the **ButtonPress** and **ButtonRelease** events
> generated by the host will be received by the guest. The smooth scroll
> **Motion** events are never received. This is why scrolling vigorously
> allows some scrolling to work, since this is the only time that
> **ButtonPress** and **ButtonRelease** events are generated by the host.
>
> To work around this issue, you can run VirtualBox with the
> `QT_XCB_NO_XI2=1` environment variable set. This disables QT's usage of
> XInput2 and has it fall back to using vanilla XInput scrolling
> behavior. In other words, to work around this issue, from a terminal,
> you can run
>
> ```
> QT_XCB_NO_XI2=1 VirtualBox
> ```
>
> This works because for vanilla XInput clients, the X server is
> required to emulate smooth scrolling using only **ButtonPress** and
> **ButtonRelease** events, which are the ones, at present, capable of being
> received by the VirtualBox guest.